# How to list all columns (including schema and table) used in a SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I need to list all of the columns (including schema and table) used in a SQL query.

The reason I am doing this is because I need to document all of the required data that is being used by a shortlist of existing Power BI reports, stored procedures and views. I am then doing a gap analysis to see what data is already available in a new environment and documenting what data needs to be migrated in order to be able to reproduce the reports, stored procedures and views that are in the shortlist.

Input

```
SELECT FullName, EmailAddress
FROM dbo.Customers t1
LEFT JOIN dbo.Customer_EmailAddress t2 ON t1.CustomerID = t2.CustomerID
```

Output should be:

```
dbo.Customers.CustomerID
dbo.Customers.FirstName
dbo.Customer_EmailAddress.CustomerID
dbo.Customer_EmailAddress.EmailAddress
```

Does anyone know of a way to do this? I need to do this for a large number of queries and I am currently doing it manually which is very time-consuming!

Comment: @DaleK unfortunately I have not found anything while Googling that I've found to be relevant. I also have not tried anything myself as I can't think of anything to do what I need to do (not familiar enough with any advanced SQL Server queries).

Comment: Side note [3+ part naming on Columns will be Deprecated](https://wp.larnu.uk/3-part-naming-on-columns-will-be-deprecated/). Also see [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/deprecated-database-engine-features-in-sql-server-2017?view=sql-server-ver15#transact-sql-1)

Comment: @DaleK Thank you, I've used the two terms interchangeably however will stick with using "column" going forward.

Comment: @Squirrel A good thing. Will force some better behaviours when writing SQL queries. Unfortunately doesn't stop people from writing code like I have in my question where you need to figure out for yourself which table/view the column comes from.

Comment: @DaleK Edit which part sorry? The Input SQL query?

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you need to do this? Like are you reviewing someone else's sql and trying to decipher query columns without any table references?

Comment: How are you queries stored: this is the starting point for the query.

Comment: @SOS I am analysing the data dependencies for a number of Power BI reports as well as stored procedures and views. This is so that I can identify any data gaps in a new environment where not everything is going to be brought across into initially.

Comment: @Kendle The queries are a mix of Power BI queries, stored procedures, as well as views.

Comment: @bradja - Yeah, I don't think there's a tool that provides that function. Closest I could think of was looking at the query plan, which someone suggested below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have a query, you can get an execution plan in XML format, E.g. by using the following code.

```
SET SHOWPLAN_XML ON;  
GO

-- your query here

select ...

GO

SET SHOWPLAN_XML OFF;  
GO
```

The execution plan contains ColumnReference elements which hold the data that you need (database, schema, table & column), E.g.:

```
<ColumnReference Database="[mydb]" Schema="[sys]" Table="[sysschobjs]" Alias="[o]" Column="id">
```

Insert the XML that you got into a table, E.g.

```
create table ExecutionPlan(id int primary key,execution_plan xml)

-- cannot insert the real XML here due to SO post length limitations
insert into ExecutionPlan values (1, '<ShowPlanXML ...');
insert into ExecutionPlan values (2, '<ShowPlanXML ...');
insert into ExecutionPlan values (3, '<ShowPlanXML ...');
```

When done with the inserts, use the following query to extract the columns

---

```
with xmlnamespaces('http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan' as ns)

select      distinct

            ep.id
           ,e.val.value ('@Database' ,'sysname')    as db 
           ,e.val.value ('@Schema'   ,'sysname')    as scm 
           ,e.val.value ('@Table'    ,'sysname')    as tab 
           ,e.val.value ('@Column'   ,'sysname')    as col 
                         
from        ExecutionPlan as ep
            cross apply execution_plan.nodes ('//ns:ColumnReference') as e (val)     

where       e.val.value ('@Database' ,'sysname') is not null

order by    id, db, scm, tab, col
```

---

```
+----+-----------------------+-------+--------------------+----------+
| id |          db           |  scm  |        tab         |   col    |
+----+-----------------------+-------+--------------------+----------+
|  1 | [mydb]                | [dbo] | [mytable]          | i        |
|  1 | [mydb]                | [dbo] | [mytable]          | v        |
|  2 | [mydb]                | [dbo] | [mytable]          | i        |
|  2 | [mydb]                | [dbo] | [mytable]          | v        |
|  3 | [mssqlsystemresource] | [sys] | [syspalnames]      | class    |
|  3 | [mssqlsystemresource] | [sys] | [syspalnames]      | name     |
|  3 | [mssqlsystemresource] | [sys] | [syspalnames]      | value    |
|  3 | [mssqlsystemresource] | [sys] | [syspalvalues]     | class    |
|  3 | [mssqlsystemresource] | [sys] | [syspalvalues]     | name     |
|  3 | [mssqlsystemresource] | [sys] | [syspalvalues]     | value    |
|  3 | [mydb]                | [sys] | [sysidxstats]      | id       |
|  3 | [mydb]                | [sys] | [sysidxstats]      | indid    |
|  3 | [mydb]                | [sys] | [sysidxstats]      | intprop  |
|  3 | [mydb]                | [sys] | [sysmultiobjrefs]  | class    |
|  3 | [mydb]                | [sys] | [sysmultiobjrefs]  | depid    |
|  3 | [mydb]                | [sys] | [sysobjvalues]     | objid    |
|  3 | [mydb]                | [sys] | [sysobjvalues]     | valclass |
|  3 | [mydb]                | [sys] | [sysobjvalues]     | valnum   |
|  3 | [mydb]                | [sys] | [sysobjvalues]     | value    |
|  3 | [mydb]                | [sys] | [sysschobjs]       | created  |
|  3 | [mydb]                | [sys] | [sysschobjs]       | id       |
|  3 | [mydb]                | [sys] | [sysschobjs]       | intprop  |
|  3 | [mydb]                | [sys] | [sysschobjs]       | modified |
|  3 | [mydb]                | [sys] | [sysschobjs]       | name     |
|  3 | [mydb]                | [sys] | [sysschobjs]       | nsclass  |
|  3 | [mydb]                | [sys] | [sysschobjs]       | nsid     |
|  3 | [mydb]                | [sys] | [sysschobjs]       | pclass   |
|  3 | [mydb]                | [sys] | [sysschobjs]       | pid      |
|  3 | [mydb]                | [sys] | [sysschobjs]       | status   |
|  3 | [mydb]                | [sys] | [sysschobjs]       | status2  |
|  3 | [mydb]                | [sys] | [sysschobjs]       | type     |
|  3 | [mydb]                | [sys] | [syssingleobjrefs] | class    |
|  3 | [mydb]                | [sys] | [syssingleobjrefs] | depid    |
|  3 | [mydb]                | [sys] | [syssingleobjrefs] | depsubid |
|  3 | [mydb]                | [sys] | [syssingleobjrefs] | indepid  |
+----+-----------------------+-------+--------------------+----------+
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=50ad313a8e53586c6d1af637f53c8ade)

P.S.
You would probably want to automate the process by writing a code (e.g. in Python) that connect to your database, pick a query, get its execution plan and save it into a table.

Comment: This did exactly what I needed. Thank you so much. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use `sp_describe_first_result_set` or [`sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-describe-first-result-set-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for this.**

For example:

```sql
create table t(id int, v varchar(30))
```

```sql
select
  name as ActualColumnName,
  concat(
  QUOTENAME(s.source_database),
  '.',
  QUOTENAME(s.source_schema),
  '.',
  QUOTENAME(s.source_table),
  '.')
  + QUOTENAME(s.source_column) AS SourceName
from sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set(N'
SELECT id, v
FROM dbo.t
', N'', 1) s;
```

The second parameter is for variables. For example:

```sql
select
  name as ActualColumnName,
  concat(
  QUOTENAME(s.source_database),
  '.',
  QUOTENAME(s.source_schema),
  '.',
  QUOTENAME(s.source_table),
  '.')
  + QUOTENAME(s.source_column) AS SourceName
from sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set(N'
SELECT id, v, @v
FROM dbo.t
', N'@v varchar(100)', 1) s
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7ec9eb62b4bcfd1cab144d8dfd38b50c)

For a list of every reference used in a query, you can use `sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities`. It only works on stored procedures though.

Comment: This return the columns of the result set, not necessarily the columns used in the query. For example if the query filters on column x and x does not appear in the SELECT clause or what is being retrieved is an expression e.g. x+1 and not x, x will not be returned.